# Column order in propel pager (symfony)

Tags: symfony1, propel, pager

i have this code in executeIndex action:

```
$pager = new sfPropelPager('News',5);
$c = new Criteria();
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->addSelectColumn(NewsPeer::ID);
$c->addSelectColumn(NewsPeer::TYTUL);
$c->addSelectColumn(NewsPeer::SLUG);
$c->addSelectColumn(NewsPeer::TEKST);
$c->addSelectColumn(NewsPeer::UTW);
$c->addSelectColumn(NewsPeer::WYSWIETLENIA);
$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(NewsPeer::UTW);
$pager->setCriteria($c);
$pager->setPage($this->getRequestParameter("p", 1));
$pager->init();
$this->pager=$pager;
```

as you can see, im selecting 6 columns from 9column table.

When i want to print UTW column in indexSuccess it print nothing. when i do: print_r($news), im getting this:

```
[id:protected] => 64
[tytul:protected] => Limit
[slug:protected] => limit
[tekst:protected] => text.....
[pelnytekst:protected] => 2011-12-22 08:54:07
[stan:protected] => 42
[utw:protected] => 
[zmi:protected] => 
[wyswietlenia:protected] =>
```

and it should be:

```
[id:protected] => 64
[tytul:protected] => Limit
[slug:protected] => limit
[tekst:protected] => text.....
[pelnytekst:protected] => 
[stan:protected] => 
[utw:protected] => 2011-12-22 08:54:07
[zmi:protected] => 
[wyswietlenia:protected] => 42
```

So, its ok, when i select columns with same order as in table, but when i skip one, values get messed up. How to fix this?

Comment: can you add the code to print UTW in the template please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the PeerMethod to 'doSelectStmt'.

```
$pager->setCriteria($c);
$pager->setPeerMethod('doSelectStmt');  // add this
$pager->setPage($this->getRequestParameter("p", 1));
$pager->init();
$this->pager=$pager;
```